# QGIS Modeller: Overwrite existing file

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

When using the [QGIS Graphical Modeller](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html) for automatic workflows, is there a way to overwrite existing files and, even better, overwriting existing files currently loaded as layer in QGIS?

Just to clearify, I use the Modeller to load `a.gpkg`, process and output it as `b.gpkg`. When `b.gpkg` exists already, QGIS throws an error message and only after I deleted `b.gpkg`, it is possible. Is there a little setting in the Modeller I've missed?

Comment: You could save the output to a separate, temporary folder and when done, tell the model to close the project, delete the old files and copy/paste the files from the temporary folder to the one you want

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with a export to Geopackage as well. I couldn't find a proper solution. I just saved the output to a geojson file. When running the modeler it would overwrite the file. Don't know if this helps for you as well.